Issue with Full Screen Display on iOS 13 - XCode
Our app's minimum supported version of iOS 13, made with XCode. While it works perfectly on iOS 14 and above, I'm encountering an issue on iOS 13 where the app doesn't display in full screen. It seems like the app is being clipped by the safe area bounds.
I've attached my SceneDelegate code in the post for reference. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(
rootView:
MainView()
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
)
self.window = window
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
}
}
func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
//
}
func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
//
}
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
//
}

I've already tried several solutions:
Replacing MainView() with a simple Color.white view to rule out any issues with the main content.
Using edgesIgnoringSafeArea.
Manually setting the frame for both the hosting controller and the window.
Additionally, I have UIRequiresFullScreen set to YES in the Info.plist, but the problem persists.
Reference behavior:
iOS 14 and above
iOS 13

Can you provide images that compare the behavior?

@benc added the reference images.

I tried to import your code, is it complete? Try adding this line, to cause the window's background to paint under your SwiftUI objects...         window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow //DEBUG_COLORS
